# How to use Firestore as a client in Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a project that has a REST API deployed in Firebase Cloud Functions. This API manages all the Firestore reads and writes of the end users. Since the API is in Cloud Functions we use the Firebase Admin SDK which will bypass the security rules.

My goal is to run the queries using the API but as a user so that the reads and writes are checked by the security rules.

I found a solution which is using the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) coupled with the [firestore-parser library](https://github.com/jdbence/firestore-parser) to get a JSON result similar to what i'm used to with the SDK. It was okay until i had to make queries with filters. To do so i need to use a [structured query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery) but the syntax is really complex and i will have to do a lot of mapping to parse a where clause from the JS writing.

So my questions are :

1. Is there a way to use directly the Firestore client SDK from the Cloud Functions?
2. If not, is there a simpler way to use the Firestore REST API?

Comment: 1. Yes. Just add the Firestore SDK to your function code as you would use it normally.  There is nothing special about this.

Comment: On the other hand - it's a secure environment; why do you NEED Firestore Security rules?  Unlike the browser, there isn't a risk of intercepted traffic and spoofing  It's your code, so bugs shouldn't be a concern.  The access is a *bit* different -but it is possible to "wrap" the admin SDK so it presents just like the clientSDK  (see @leaddreamer/firebase-wrapper on GitHub & npm for a 95% complete example of this- I use the *same* business library on both client and Cloud Functions for this very reason).

Comment: @DougStevenson Normally, using the client SDK i would be authenticated (using Firebase-Auth) then i make the Firestore queries. Inside the Cloud Functions, should i authenticate before each query? And is it possible to authenticate using only the ID Token?

Comment: @LeadDreamer I want to rely on Firestore's seurity rules to manage users access to data.

Comment: Security rules don't apply to code running on backends.  It only applies to web and mobile SDKs.  So what you're trying to do isn't possible.  This is an FAQ.

Comment: @Jrawat The Cloud Functions are *already* running in an authenticated state - it's a fully secure environment - which is why you don't need further authentication.  *User* access and authentication is in the *browser* client, and completely separate from the back-end.

Comment: BTW, the approach you describe is NOT a good use of Cloud Functions, especially with latencies etc.  Google already supplies extensive and secure tools for the client to access the Database.  Forcing ALL user access through Cloud Functions is a TERRIBLE bottleneck.

Comment: That said, I *do* have a few Cloud Functions to manage *very, very* specific situations that involve rare-ish cases where the access needed is beyond the Security Rules capabilities.  Never-the-less, 99% of database access is directly from the client.